# Nextflow: split or subset a channel containing tuples

Tags: channel, nextflow

I have joined  two channels as a way of filtering out items that do not have all the necessary files. The resulting items of the joined channel look like:

```
[sample1, [sample1.csv], [sample1_1.fastq, sample1_2.fastq]]
```

I now wish to remove the `csv` entry so that the items of the channel have the form:

```
[sample1, [sample1_1.fastq, sample1_2.fastq]]
```

for use in existing downstream processes.

I've been looking at [multiMap](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#multimap) and [branch](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#branch) but can't seem to find anything that does what I want. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#map) operator for this:

```
joined_ch
    .map { sample, csv_files, fastq_files ->

        tuple( sample, fastq_files )
    }
    .view()
```

Comment: Thank you! For whatever reason I just couldn't see it and apply it!